# How to get more than month records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a question in SQL Server on how to get more than month records?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [doj] [date] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2020-04-05' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2021-11-09' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2021-11-08' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-10-04' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2021-11-20' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2021-11-07' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2021-11-10' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([empid], [doj]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2021-12-03' AS Date))
```

based on above data I want output like below

```
empid   |doj    
1       |2020-04-05 
4       |2021-10-04
2       |2021-11-09
7       |2021-11-10
```

I tried like below

```
SELECT [empid], [doj]
FROM [emp]
WHERE datediff(mm,doj,getdate()) > 1
```

The above query is missing one month one day and one month 2days records.

Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: I don't get it. You says for more than one month, give an example that would give data that is last month or later, but want data from April last year as well as October and November this year?

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server 2021 & 2016 - which is it? Please only tag the version of interest.

Comment: [The `DATEDIFF` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) *doesn't* count the number of months between two dates; it counts the number of month *boundaries* crossed between the two dates. Both `DATEDIFF(month, '20211130', '20211201')` and `DATEDIFF(month, '20211101', '20211231')` will return `1`.

Comment: How much effort do you save have typing `datediff(mm,` and how much more readable is `datediff(month,`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your main problem is in the where clause

```
WHERE datediff(mm,doj,getdate()) > 1
```

DATEDIFF (for months) finds the absolute differences in months e.g., the difference between 30 March 2021 and 31 March 2021 is 0 months, but the difference between 31 March 2021 and 1 April 2021 is 1 month. Similarly, the difference between 1 March 2021 and 30 April 2021 is also 1 month.

In other words - when doing a DATEDIFF on months, it ignores any finer details such as days and time of day, and just compares how many months between (say) March 2021 and April 2021.

Therefore, if you want to get data from more than 1 month ago, it's better to determine what 1 month ago was (as a day) then work out what occurred before then. It's also more efficient (as a bonus).

```
WHERE  doj <= DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())
```

Adding -1 months to getdate() takes away an exact month (so as today is 9 December, adding -1 month makes 9 November). You then find any `doj` records that occurred before it.